# paired vs two sample t-test

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

It's been awhile since taking Prob. & Stats in college. My question is regarding which test to use in the following situation. I have two data sets that contain values regarding some testing/quality control procedure in a manufacturing process.

The first data set is when this particular testing/quality control procedure was being carried out by a human, while the second data set is when this same testing/quality control procedure was being done by a robot.

I would like to find out whether or not there is a significant relationship between these two data sets, using the t-test. A coworker had recommended the paired t-test, but as I am refreshing my knowledge on prob & stats, it seems like the 2-sample (independent) t-test would be more appropriate in this situation.

My question is basically: Which one should I use? The paired or the 2-sample t-test?

Comment: So what is the variable being measured and are you comparing one test versus another on the same sample subjects?

Comment: Good questions. There are several variables being measured, but each one will have their own t-test. One variable, for example, would be the percentage of alcohol found within some solution. The second question I am not too sure about. Lets say that in case (1) the exact same solutions were being measured (same product, unit/serial number) and in case (2) same product but different unit/serial number.

Comment: The paired t-test is appropriate to use when comparing measurements taken on the same subject often before and after a treatment involving many different subjects. In your particular case, this would be appropriate if the two methods of measurement were applied to identical samples. But if "all" the samples are identical (I assume there are many test samples) there is nothing to gain from it. From what you say, I'm not sure what your situation is. The reason for this is because we want to measure the difference in measurement methods and not the differences between samples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are 19 unique tests. For these 19 unique tests, 30 samples are being tested. One data set contains the 19x30 matrix where these tests were performed by a robot. A second data set contains another 19x30 matrix of values where these tests were performed by a human. So, yes, we're testing to see whether or not there is a statistical difference between the measurement methods. Ultimately I would like to combine all the p-values for all 19 tests and do a "meta-analysis" of sorts.

Comment: (And the samples being tested are the same.)

Comment: Sounds like a straight forward 2 sample t-test for a difference in means is best. With the samples all being the same, there is no criteria for pairing. That is, any one sample is the same as any of the 59 others.

Comment: Thank you Phil H. That was my initial intuition.

Comment: Maybe you should also test whether variances are equal. Robots might have more or less variability than humans in performing such tasks. // Best to use a Welch 2-sample t test to check for difference in means (not requiring variances to be equal). Then as a separate issue maybe test whether variances are equal. (F-test if data are clearly normal; nonparametric alternative if not. F-tests for differences in variance are somewhat less robust than t-tests for differences in means.)